# browser.cookies.getAll({ url: url }) retrieves nothing even though on the developer tool is present

Tags: javascript, add-on, browser-extension

I want to make a download manager browser extension that retrieve the cookies from the website that serving the file. I have tried this method before and it was working flawlessly. But now it seems always retrieve empty array (maybe after I update my pc (?). I'm not sure). Here is my code

```js
browser.downloads.onCreated.addListener(item => {
    browser.cookies.getAll({ url: item.url }).then(cookies => console.log(cookies))
})
```

my manifest

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Download Manager",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Firedox add-on for Download Manager",
    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/48.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "downloads",
        "cookies"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "download.js"
        ]
    },
    "browser_specific_settings": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "downloader@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running on Fedora Linux 37 with Firefox 116